# Request validation in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm designing 2 websites. The first to upload images and the second to store the images as an image hosting (both of them are using asp.net mvc 5).

The domain name of the first website is: `vinachannel.com`.

In the first website, I wanna send some images to the hosting via ajax:

```
var f = new FormData();
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://myimagehosting.com/home/upload',
   type: 'POST',
   data: f,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false
}).done(function (data) {
   // logic...
})
```

Action `Upload` in `Home` controller of the hosting:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload()
{
   if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
   {
      // start uploading...
   }
}
```

Now, my problem is: I wanna the image hosting accepts only the requests which are sent from `vinachannel.com`. Just like:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload()
{
   if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("vinachannel.com"))
   {
      // start uploading...
   }
}
```

or using regex:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"^(https://)?(www\.)?(vinachannel\.com)(.+)$");
if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && reg.IsMatch(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri))
{
   // start uploading...
}
```

My question: How can I custom an attribute to validate all requests for action `Upload`?

```
[VinaChannel] // only requests from site vinachannel.com
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload()
{
   // ...
}
```

**UPDATE:** (based on @David's comment and following [the article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters))

```
public class VinaChannelFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var reg = new Regex(@"^(https://)?(www\.)?(vinachannel\.com)(.+)$");
        if (reg.IsMatch(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri))
        {
           // what's next here...?
        }
        this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a custom `ActionFilter` subclassed from `ActionFilterAttribute`.  Look at this article: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters

Comment: @DavidTansey I've just tried based on your advice but I cannot complete it. Can you help me the last part?

Comment: you want to add this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext); inside your if since that you want to execute action if it matched regex otherwise send it some where else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a custom action filter which inspects the request headers and see where the request is coming from and use that values to determine, whether to allow /deny further processing. the `Referer` header is the one you might want to use.

```
public class VerifyDomain : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var expectedHost = "domainnameyouwanttocheck";
        var headers = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(headers["Referer"]) 
                                      && new Uri(headers["Referer"]).Host == expectedHost)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }           
    }
}
```

And decorate your action method/controller with the action filter

```
[VerifyDomain]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
  // to do : return something
}
```

When this endpoint is being accessed from anywhere other than the value you have in the `expectedHost` variable, the caller will get `401 Unauthorized` response. You may update the if condition to check for a list of expectedHost name's to support your local development environment as well.

Comment: You are welcome. You should be checking the `Referred` , not `Host` . See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Upload()` is on `myimagehosting.com`, right? Then `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` will return Uri on `myimagehosting.com` domain, to get source address you need to get referrer: `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath`. But the problem is, it can be easily forged, so depending on your needs, you probably will have to implement more complex Authentication/Authorization logic

Comment: Thanks! I will remember it.